# JMeter - Selecting Part of a Regular Expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a JMeter Regular Expression Extractor which searches for the following regular expression:

```
myId=[0-9]{10}
```

This retrieves the 10 digit numeric id number from my websites form. I then set a "Reference Name" of myId for the id number. My template value is $0$ and my match No. is set to blank.

In my HTTP Request, I then pass a parameter value of:

```
${myId}
```

When I run my JMeter test, it inserts text in the form of:

```
myId=myId=1234567890
```

How do I get rid of the duplicate myId=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about JMeter's implementation of RegEx but normally

```
myId=[0-9]{10}
```

would match everything, including `myId=`.  What you need is to define capture groups that you want extracted using () and then you will reference the capture group array and get the item you want.  E.g.

```
myId=([0-9]{10})
```

group 0 would still be the whole thing but group 1 would be just the numeric portion as delimited by (), i.e. without `myId=`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting idea, unfortunately JMeter doesn't seem to respect the parentheses. I tried this before posting, but it didn't work.

Comment: Actually your answer did work. I added the parentheses AND set the template to "$1" instead of "$0$" and it worked.

Comment: well, ain't that groovy?  glad to be of help