# Match on ID in URL with RegEx

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am looking to find a random alpha-numeric ID from a URL returned in some JSON.  Using the example:

```
"responseURL" : "http://sutureself.com/userid/123abc"
```

... I want to just match on the `123abc`.  So far I have:

```
http://sutureself.com/userid/([a-z0-9]+)
```

... but this matches the whole URL.  What do I need to add to only match this ID?  Note, the length of the ID can differ.

Comment: Are you looking for `[^/]+$`

Comment: And what's in your capture group there after the match? Is it not what you want?

Comment: @unigeek No, what it captures is `http://sutureself.com/userid/123abc`, I just want `123abc`.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @devnull Close, but this includes the ending quotation mark and the closing brackets of the JSON.

Comment: @MElliott I'm using the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. I tested it with Rubular (http://rubular.com/). Just had to escape the forward slashes in your regex (use "http:\/\/sutureself.com\/userid\/([a-z0-9]+)"). The capture group looks good.

Comment: @unigeek I was using RegExPal (http://regexpal.com/).  Looks like the problem was in my JMeter test, using template `$0$` instead of `$1$`.  Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the template to "$1". See comments in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279861/jmeter-selecting-part-of-a-regular-expression) related post.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
[^/]+(?="})
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/pT3fG8